# Можно ли рашифровать код, закодированный в md5?

Tags: шифрование, md5

Можно ли расшифровать код, закодированный в системе md5? Если можно, то скажите как.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду хэши паролей (обычно достаточно коротких) или можно ли имея MD5 (16 байт) восстановить длинный текст, по которому этот MD5 получен ?

Второе - нет. Таких текстов "бесконечно" много (но найти подходящий сложно).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

md5 - необратимый хеш, единственный вариант это перебор. 
Функции типа md5_decode() нету если вы об этом :)

Answer (score 3):

Они не брутятся, они подбираются по словарям. Есть слухи, что есть словари на все комбинации до 8 знаков, включительно.

Проблема в том, что из-за слабости алгоритма МД5 - сложная мега строкая на 10000 знаков, может давать такой же хеш, как строка в 5 байт. И вот эту строку реально найти. 
И для пробивки пароля - её хватит.

Используйте более новые алгоритмы, используйте соль. Используйте многопроходность.
Словарей на 4-5 мд5 вложенно мне думается ещё пока и нет. Причем присаливать можно скажем на 2-3 круге, что потребует просчета для вас отдельного словаря, а это уже большая честь.
Используйте в довесок к общепринятой защите - интересные находки.
Тогда потенциальный взломщик пять раз проклянет, и один раз плюнет.

Comment: Как хорошему знатоку задам вопрос. Если я кодирую в md5 пароль, и кодирую в md5 любое совпадение, толи это будет банальное mt_rand толи просто time(). При запросе к БД извлечь пароль будет прописана функция которая извлечет из БД все 64 символа, обрежет 32 последних имвола и с первыи 32-мя сверит пароль. На сколько высока такая защита?

Comment: Словари на md5 вложено есть уже давно(пичем как на 2ойную так и на 3ойную), на sha аналогично, просто sha намного дольше подбирается посему даже имея словарь подбирать будешь до старости :)<br>
PS:не баньте меня я не хакер xDDD

Comment: @Palmervan, излишества, достаточно sha1 + rand соль..<br>
О md5 забудьте навсегда вообще :)<br>
Если безопасность столь важна - нужно смотреть в сторону https...

Comment: Портал катать под https? не гон ли?

Comment: Но если он помешан на безопасности, то пусть делает.

Comment: Вот меня поражает когда так невнимательно читают, что я пишу, и так дико удивляются... повторюсь:<br><b>Если безопасность столь важна</b><br>И какбы при написании порталов безопасность не столь важна...<br>Если короче - <b>https не для порталов</b>

Comment: Зачем весь портал, только авторизацию.
Собственно сейчас все так и делают, один gmail всё через SSL гоняет)

Answer (score 0):

Поиск google и запрос типа брут md5
Чтива на недели две, но результат 0!

Приведу пример: 1 символ любого алфавита закодирует в 32-х значную строку. 2 символа, 3 символа и т.д. всервано закодирует в 32-х значную строку. Тут даже вычеслять не стоит и тратить время!

Comment: На самом деле они брутятся на ура, если знать точно систему шифрования, вообще не вопрос. Для этого используются ресурсы видеокарты, я особо не читерил в этом направлении, но если интерестно, можете погуглить что-то подобное...<br>
PS:после прочтения этого чтива - md5 не использую, юзаю как минимум sha1 и то стараюсь с солью и все формы на токенах делать :D<br>
<small>дада, там страшные вещи пишут, тут наверное меньше знаешь... xD</small>

Comment: токен вещь хорошая, очень полезная. Суть в том что если человек спрашивает как и не имеет хоть малейшего понятия, то 5% что он возьмется это делать! А sha1 возьму на вооружение)